# How to change innerHTML after a class transition has taken place - Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

So I'm doing a little bit of DOM manipulations. Namely, adding some form hints on the fly. As the user types, little error messages show up and go away. The problem is, changing the HTML happens before the CSS transition can take place.

For example:

```
      element.previousSibling.classList.remove('active-error')
      element.previousSibling.innerHTML = ''
```

Even though the innerHTML comes after, the class change before it takes .75 seconds to animate.

This is my workaround solution:

```
      element.previousSibling.classList.remove('active-error')
      setTimeout(function() {
        element.previousSibling.innerHTML = ''
      }, 1500) // This is hardcoded to match the transition time in the CSS (Is there a solution)
```

Is there a better way to write the JavaScript so I don't have to rely on keeping my CSS and JS in sync (.75s = 1500 milliseconds)?

I'm looking for pure JavaScript, no jQuery.

Comment: Nah, not with vanilla JS. Libraries would help, but ultimately they'll just do what you're doing here - manage timings.

Comment: Good devs don't use timers when events are available. use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend events, instead of a hard-coded timer. they are well-spported and will keep you from cross-linking CSS and JS.

Comment: Do you really need to clear the HTML?

Comment: @Malk I need to change the text of the HTML, I suppose there are other ways, but do they help my need?

Comment: @dandavis, Hmm... the listener is such a tricky thing to handle, I need something that fires once when I tell it to, not every time the element goes through a transition.

Comment: @Costa: then add the event before you do your thing, and remove it from the event callback. if you name the callback `me`, then `this.removeEventListener("transitionend", me);`

Comment: You should set up a sample, or at least include the CSS transition definitions. Advice depends on what you mean by "go away". If the container is hidden, for instance, the text can stay populated. If the width is shrunk, you might need overflow:hidden on the container.

Comment: Relevant fiddle, but jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/82vg42b1/